# Is it possible to serve a string via a URL request from one Javascript to another?

Tags: javascript

I am not even sure that what I ask is possible at all, but maybe somebody would be able to give me some ideas...

Here is the situation. I have a certain third-party Javascript module which is being run in browser. The module exposes an API call which loads some configuration (XML file) from a provided URL. I would like to pass it instead some XML which I generate in my own script. I cannot change the module; so, what I am looking for is some way to specify some URL which will serve my local data. Is there any way to do something like this?

Comment: We will need to see the actual module code to understand what options might be available to "hook" or "replace" its request for a configuration URL with your own XML.  There are no generic answers without seeing the actual code you are trying to influence.

Comment: Is this third party module configurable? How is third party module initialized?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot give you the module code. Let's assume that the module exposes a loadConfig(url) call.

Comment: Have you tried using the [`javascript:` protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767736%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to provide data as in a `loadConfig("javascript:" + xmlDataString) ` call.?

Comment: Maybe you can use a `data:` URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing with the "javascript:" pseudo protocol didn't work - making it look like XMLHttpRequest does not accept "pseudo" protocols.

Testing with [data URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs) did work:

```
var xmlSource =
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<text>
<para>hello world</para>
</text>
`;
var xmlDataURL = "data:text/xml," + xmlSource;

loadConfig( xmlDataURL);
```

was succesfully sent using a dummy version of loadConfig:

```
// Dummy loadConfig:
function loadConfig( url)
{  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   req.open("GET", url);
   req.onreadystatechange = function ()
   {   if( req.readyState == 4)
           console.log(req.responseText);
   };
   req.send();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a nice idea - let me try it!